# skype javascript plugin format

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, skype

I'm trying to integrate skype button in the header file of wordpress (header.php) and its successfully been integrated into the file, but I'm facing difficulty with the format, as I was having mail-id, phone number and skype displaying in the same line, now its displaying one in each line.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.skypeassets.com/i/scom/js/skype-uri.js"></script>
<div id="SkypeButton_Call_mspchelp_1">
<script type="text/javascript">
Skype.ui({
  "name": "dropdown",
  "element": "SkypeButton_Call_mspchelp_1",
  "participants": ["mspchelp"],
  "imageSize": 24
});
</script>
</div>
```

and [this link](http://mspchelp.com) where I'm utilizing this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this on each element:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Here's the output, i edited some css alignment.

screenshot:

[image]

then rearrange your HTML order to:

`mail-id, phone number, skype`

your current html order is:

```
mail-id,  skype, phone number
```

Comment: try to remove the z-index of your top-bar. the reason is because your menu were overlapped by the top-bar.

Comment: Hey Dyrandz, I can't find any z-index file please review the file where I'm making changes [header.php](http://mspchelp.com/wp-content/themes/Doors/header.php)

Comment: it's on the css. `.top-bar`  in your css. remove this line `z-index: 10`